# Could not load file or assembly "". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, filezilla

I have a web project in ASP.NET and I want to upload this project to FTP with Filezilla. First I'm publishing this project in Visual Studio 2013. After deploying with Filezilla. But I'm getting this error every time.

So, these are that I'm getting from Chrome:

```
Server Error in '/emre.solugan' Application. Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) 

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)
Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework' could not be loaded.
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
Stack Trace: [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0   
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34 
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152 
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77 
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16 System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28 
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38 [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)] 
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736 
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217 
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153 
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9932052 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```